# Echo Warning and notice while testing Laravel project

Tags: phpunit, laravel-testing

I want to echo **warnings** manually in some situation while testing Laravel project.

Answer (score 0):

use addWarning method

```
public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $this->addWarning('There is not enough record in actual database to test pagination');
    }
```